# Floating Point numbers on VAX machine

Tags: floating-point, reverse-engineering, ieee-754, floating, vax

I have the source code in RTL/2 program languange of an old application  running on a VAX machine.
Unfortunately I don't have the possibility\ability to re-compile the application.
I have to change some coefficent ( real numbers, "code wired")

So I had an idea: i could change directly these numbers in the executables ( some .cm8 files, these are big files where all lines start with a ":" then a sort of ADDRESS and the HEX data)

unfortunately if i take for istance one of the coefficents (es 3.8262619e-09) and i rapresent it in binary I obtain:

```
es 3.8262619e-09 In binary is : 00110001100000110111100000101000 hex is: 0x31837828  hex in reverse endianess:  0x28788331
```

But if I search for those HEX in the executable files... I do not find matches. If i could find these number in the executable i would like to change them directly.
The problem, I presume, is that the VAX machine does not rapresent floating point using IEEE 754 standard.
I found this link
https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nssdc/formats/VAXFloatingPoint.htm
Which explains the floating point rapresentation on a vax machine,
But I do not understand how to rapresent my real numbers ( es the 0.38262619E-08 I found directly in the source code) in VAX floating point format.

Any help?

Comment: a VAX machine is still in use nowadays? Anyway this is probably more suitable on [retrocomputing.se] or [reverseengineering.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that the format used for the floating-point data is the 32-bit VAX `F_floating` format. This is similar to IEEE-754 `binary32`. A normalized binary floating-point format, allowing the most significant bit of the significand (mantissa) to be assumed to be 1 and not stored. Both use an 8-bit biased exponent.

The `binary32` format has a significand range of [1, 2) while `F_floating` has a significand range of [0.5, 1). The exponent bias used by the `binary32` format is 127 while the exponent bias of the `F_floating` format is 128. In combination, this means that identical encodings in the two formats are numerically offset by a factor of four. The `F_floating` format does not support signed zero, subnormals, infinities, and NaNs.

Because of compatibility with the 16-bit PDP-11, `F_floating` uses a non-intuitive byte storage ordering. When examining the memory image in ascending address order, the four bytes of a `F_floating` operand occur in the order 2, 3, 0, 1.

For the following ISO-C99 program, I assume that the code is executing on a system that utilizes IEEE-754 floating-point arithmetic.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a)
{
    uint32_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

/* Convert a IEEE-754 'binary32' operand into VAX F-float format, represented 
   by a sequence of four bytes in ascending address order. Underflow is handled 
   with a flush-to-zero response. Overflow is not handled!
*/
void float_to_vaxf (float a, uint8_t *b)
{
    const float TWO_TO_M128 = 2.93873588e-39f; // 2**(-128)
    const float SCAL = 4; // factor between IEEE-754 'binary32' and VAX F-float
    const float ZERO = 0.0f; // canonical zero
    uint32_t t;
    // adjust for exponent bias and significant range
    a = a * SCAL;
    // no support for subnormals in VAX F_floating, flush to zero
    if (fabsf (a) < TWO_TO_M128) a = ZERO;
    t = float_as_uint32 (a);
    // adjust to VAX F_floating byte ordering
    b[0] = (uint8_t)(t >> 2 * CHAR_BIT);
    b[1] = (uint8_t)(t >> 3 * CHAR_BIT);
    b[2] = (uint8_t)(t >> 0 * CHAR_BIT);
    b[3] = (uint8_t)(t >> 1 * CHAR_BIT);
}

int main (void)
{
    float a = 3.8262619e-9f;
    uint8_t vf[4];
    float_to_vaxf (a, vf);
    printf ("% 15.8e as VAX F-float bytes: 0x%02x,0x%02x,0x%02x,0x%02x\n", 
            a, vf[0], vf[1], vf[2], vf[3]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Hello Njuffa; 

 I tried your solution and actually I can find the.hex code generated by the conversion (I compiled and used your program) in some files.exe. For example if I have the file "example.rtl", in which there is a float number "x", I find the number "x" converted to hex in the file "example.exe".

 This is definitely a step forward for me. Unfortunately I am still missing a step. I can't find how the different files.exe for the eeprom are "mapped". I must be able to edit the file to be uploaded directly to eprom. 

In the meantime thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Update: using the conversion formula provided by njuffa i found the hex rapresentation of some real numbers in a .exe file. 
Unfortunately I cannot find the hex string into EPROM files.
So i presume the target machine is not VAX ( probably the VAX machine was the host machine from which they compiled for an intel 8087).
I opened another question, because I think this is solved by njuffa. thanks again